# Need some feedback for eyelid modeling/ topology

Tags: modeling, rigging

I have created a model (attached) and am now trying to rig it. But I'm not sure if the eyelid topology is any good. It'd be great if someone could take a look and correct me if it is crappy for animating blinks.

*.blend file here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to create a topology more like this one:

[image]

So that when you rig with rows of bones, you can more easily fold the eyelid this way:

[image]